# Can I batch file upload videos on YouTube?

Tags: batch-file, youtube

Recently, I've found myself doing a very long but repeated process of editing and uploading certain kind of videos online on YouTube. My friend suggested to write a batch file or a script as he said to help with the process, so I've decided to learn how to write it.

But first is that even possible? to write script file that open certain programs and do certain processes. And might open browser and click on certain buttons and make that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Youtube-upload](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload)

It's a command-line Python script that uploads videos to YouTube. It should work on any platform (OS X, Windows, etc) that runs Python. It is using the YouTube [API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

If you are looking to automate the operation of Windows software. Look into [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) which provides a GUI and a simple basic-like scripting language to do so.

Comment: thank you a lot for that.. but about the second half of that.. opening other programs, Am I in need to something like this one or I can write one?